# Adding count down timer in perl template tool kit

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, countdowntimer, template-toolkit

I have checked some possibilities for adding a count down timer in a cgi page.But i couldn't find anything helpful.

I have written the file to add countdown timer, 'Timer.js' and is calling from the html file 'timer.html'.My problem is i want to pass a value from my cgi template tool kit file to timer.html file as the starting of the timer.

my template file is edit.html.tmpl

i have a table in this template file, and in the 3rd column i want to add the count down timer.just like below, i called the counter there by hardcording the starting value in the template file :

```
<td align="center">
[% PROCESS bug/timer.html %]
</td>
```

I want to pass the below value to the timer.html file as the starting of the timer.

```
<td align="center">
      <input name="estimated_time" id="estimated_time"
             value="[% PROCESS formattimeunit
                               time_unit=bug.estimated_time %]"
             size="6" maxlength="6">
      <input type = "Hidden" name="estimate_time" id="estimate_time" value="[% bug.estimated_time %]" size="6" maxlength="6">
    </td>
```

How can i achieve this????can anyone please help me in doing this??

Comment: So you need to get a value from your `[% PROCESS bug/timer.html %]` call into your `Timer.js` JavaScript? How is the timer JavaScript started? Couldn't you just set a value in a `<script>` inside your `timer.html` template and then the timer JavaScript could read it?

Comment: i want to get the value bug.estimated_time from the tmpl file to the timer as the starting value .

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer("timer",60);</script>

in the place of 60, i want the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put your JavaScript in that template then you could do it the easy way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", [% bug.estimated_time %]);
</script>
```

If the `CreateTimer` call is elsewhere, then you could set a value in your `bug/timer.html` template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.timer_time = [% bug.estimated_time %];
</script>
```

and then use that value later:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", window.timer_time);
</script>
```

That assumes that the `window.onload` script will occur after the `window.timer_time` script, if that's not the case then you'll have to force the issue with something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    CreateTimer('timer', window.timer_time)();
}
```

Comment: Thank you...it is working fine now....
i have one doubt too....i don't want to reset the timer every time the window load.once the timer get started by getting the bug.estimated_time value, it will count down till becomes 0 without any stop. what can i do for that??

Comment: I suppose you could store the timer value in a cookie and then get `CreateTimer` to check the cookie and fall back to its second argument.